# responseText contains null/undefined in safari

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

Here is my js and problem:

```
function refreshDiagValues()
{
    var xmlhttp = null;
    var recv;

    try { 
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari 
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } catch (e) {
        // Internet Explorer 
        try { 
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
        } catch (e) { 
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        } 
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            recv=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("text7").innerHTML = recv;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_DGS0101", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I could get this work in IE and chrome, but fails in safari.

I tested it by changing `document.getElementById("text7").innerHTML = 5`  and it shows the correct number on all browsers.

It feels like `responseText` does not contain any value for safari, but contains results for chrome and IE.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Why not use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? instead of re-inventing the wheel and solving all cross-browser issues yourself?

Comment: what is this path: "ajax_DGS0101"??

Comment: I implement this into my arm processor, when I open this website using my smartphone though wifi module, the website would sent ajax_DGS0101 to my processor ask for data back.

Comment: I tried jQuery but it could not work, maybe I should try it again. I would make this working for safari.